# Grid with swing components in the upper left corner of a panel

Tags: java, swing, layout

I tried several layout manager (BoxLayout, BorderLayout, GridBagLayout) but I don't get what I want... I have to layout four components.

```
JLabel label1 = new JLabel("This is label 1");
JLabel label2 = new JLabel("This is another label");
SpinnerModel spinnerModel1 = new SpinnerNumberModel(-1, -1, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1);
SpinnerModel spinnerModel2 = new SpinnerNumberModel(-1, -1, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1);
JSpinner spinner1 = new JSpinner(spinnerModel1);
JSpinner spinner2 = new JSpinner(spinnerModel2);
```

They should appear at the upper left corner of my panel.

[image]

First, I am not sure which layout would serve my needs. I though I would be happy with BoxLayout but then I cannot layout the grid part (the spinner would not get the same heights like the labels or the labels would not occupy the same space). I tried to use the GridBagLayout but I don't know how to define the "remaining space". I don't want to set a fixed number of grid-rows / -columns. But maybe I did miss something?
Or I need to combine layout manager?
Any suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at the SpringLayout: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html

Comment: you could learn MiG Layout (http://www.miglayout.com/) and then never need another LayoutManager again.

Comment: You're not limited to one layout manager, nesting layouts is the preferred method for most non trivial GUIs. Place the grid in a container (with `GridBagLayout` perhaps), and then place that container using whatever layout manager suits the overall design.

Comment: `BoxLayout` against the Y_AXIS on the parent container, and each row is an individual `JPanel` with a `FlowLayout` (set to LEFT). This is normally how I stack lists in GUIs.

Comment: This would make it difficult to get the columns to align correctly when the labels are different lengths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using GridBagLayout within FlowLayout. So far the most elegant way to do it with the standard layout managers:

```
    JPanel optionsPanel = new JPanel();

    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("This is label 1");
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("This is another label");
    SpinnerModel spinnerModel1 = new SpinnerNumberModel(-1, -1, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1);
    SpinnerModel spinnerModel2 = new SpinnerNumberModel(-1, -1, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1);
    JSpinner spinner1 = new JSpinner(spinnerModel1);
    JSpinner spinner2 = new JSpinner(spinnerModel2);

    JPanel gridPanel = new JPanel();
    gridPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    gridPanel.add(label1, c);
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    gridPanel.add(label2, c);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    gridPanel.add(spinner1, c);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 1;
    gridPanel.add(spinner2, c);

    optionsPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
    optionsPanel.add(gridPanel);
```

Thanks a lot for all hints.